# What is this proof in a number theory video?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, totient-function

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zP09Dw5D8nY

Here at precisely **31:00**, he puts up a second claim, where $|A_d| \leq \phi(n)$where $A_d$ $=$ {$1 \leq a \leq p-1 | ord_p(a) = d$}, $d|p-1$ and $p$ is prime.
(I understood the first one)

His proof is something which I am not able to understand, and I think he messed up somewhere.

**His Claim:**

Claim:  If $A_d$ is not empty.

$|A_d| \leq \phi(n)$ for $A_d$ $=$ {$1 \leq a \leq p-1 | ord_p(a) = d$}, $d|p-1$ and $p$ is prime.

**His Proof:**

Take $f(x) \equiv x^d-1 \pmod{p}$ and $f(x) \equiv x^m-1 \pmod{p}$ where $m|d$.

He says that $A_d$ is the solutions of $g(x)$ removed from $f(x)$ which is understandable for $d$ being order.

Now he says that it will be $\phi(n)$ by defination.

This I don't understand, the words which he used to explain this statement are not clear to me, if you refer to the video you can understand what he is trying to say.

**Question:** What is he trying to do here?

Comment: The link didn't take me to 31:00 of some video. Instead, I got some random ads picked by youtube. Not gonna bother.

Comment: I do not know what issues Jyrki Lahtonen or others may have with YouTube and its advertisements. This takes me to a video by Michael Penn titled "The order of an integer modulo n -- Number Theory 16". However, this is why you should make your question self-contained, not relying on exterior sources to define the problem and the notation (other than commonly used mathematical notation). In particular, you should have defined what $A_d$ is (and it would be helpful to specify that $\phi$ is the Euler totient function, though in number theory, that is the obvious guess).

Comment: FYI - He did not mess up, at least in that $A_d$ is the roots modulo $p$ of $f$ with the roots of $g_m(x) = x^m-1$ for all $m < d$ removed is exactly the definition of $\phi$ of $m$ rephrased in terms of these polymomials. That it would be sufficient to only remove the roots of $g_m$ for $m \mid d$ requires some proving. Fix your question if you want to know more.

Comment: How do I fix it exactly?

Comment: @PaulSinclair  I know that but how does removing it exactly mean $\phi(n)$

Comment: I already described how to fix it! I admit I see now you did include the definition $A_d$, but only well after you started talking about it. You need to define $A_d$ when you FIRST start talking about it, not leaving your audience in the dark about what the heck it is until the middle of the discussion.

Comment: Sorry I will update it at once